# WinAppDriver. Не могу запустить приложение как администратор

Tags: c#

Необходимо автоматизировать приложение desktop windows. Но мне нужно запустить приложение как администратор. Но когда я выбираю запуск под администратором то открывается popup c данными для ввода пароляю Возможно кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой, можно ли автоматизировать такой popup или каким-то образом его отключить?

Я использую Windows 10, application на C#. Добавляю мой hooks file где я создаю инстанс driver.

```
    namespace ZenTests
{
    using BoDi;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Windows;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
    using System;
    using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
    using Zeiss.Micro.EM.DeltaServerInterface.RunTimeTests;

    [Binding]
    public class Hooks
    {
        private const string WindowsAppDriverUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:4723";
        private const string AppDirectory = "C:\\Program Files\\Carl Zeiss\\Delta1_5\\Zen\\ZEN.exe";
        protected static WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> _driver;

        [BeforeScenario]
        public static void SetUp()
        {
            if (_driver == null)
            {
                DesiredCapabilities appCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
                appCapabilities.SetCapability("app", @AppDirectory );
                appCapabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
                _driver = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(WindowsAppDriverUrl), appCapabilities);
                Assert.IsNotNull(_driver);
                _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5);
                _driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                ScenarioContext.Current["driver"] = _driver;
            }
        }
```

Этот popup  открывается при запуске под администратором

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А саму программы запускаэте как админ?

Comment: да, я по умолчанию поставила запускать под админом